# Derivation of Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, canonical-conjugation

In the [Derivation of Hamilton Jacobi Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njzPk.jpg), I didn't understand the bold parts:

we can write (1) formally as,
$$
\frac{\partial F\left(q_i, Q_i, t\right)}{\partial t}=-H\left(p_i, q_i, t\right)=-H\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}, q_i, t\right) .\tag{2}
$$
(2) will thus be an **equation with a single dependent variable $F$** and $(f+1)$ independent variables $\left(q_i\right.$, and $\left.t\right)$.

**The method of separation of variables operates when $H$ does not explicitly involve the time**. We put $F=T+f\left(q_i, Q_i\right)$ where $T$ is a function of $t$ alone, and we get
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=-H\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}, q_i\right)
$$
The left hand side is a function of $t$ alone while **the right hand side of $q_i$ 's is not involving $t$**. Hence they must be equal to a constant, say, $-$. Then,
$$
F=-E t+f\left(q_i, Q_i\right)
$$
To proceed further, **we split up $f\left(q_1, q_2 \ldots \ldots q_i \ldots \ldots\right)$ into $f_1\left(q_1\right)+f_2\left(q_2\right)+\ldots \ldots \ldots f\left(q_i\right)$**, where the symbols are obvious : $f_i$ involves only the coordinate $q_i$. **Equation (2) would now split up into the form :
function of $\left(q_1\right)=$ function of $\left(q_2, q_3 \ldots \ldots . . q_f\right)$ not involving $q_1$**. This would again be a constant. The process of separation of the variables will thus go on at each stage throwing out a constant, so that finally the solution will be of the form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
F & =F\left(q_i, Q_i, t\right) \\
& =F\left(q_i, \alpha_i, t\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
**where $\alpha_i$ 's are the '$f$' constants in the process of separation of variables**, one of which is just $E$. Again we know that with (1) satisfied the $Q_i$ 's will all be constants, so we make the identitification:
$$
Q_i \equiv \alpha_i
$$

In this above derivation, I didn't understand (in chronological order)

1. how it is an equation of single dependent variable $F$?
2. Why the method of separation of variables operates when $H$ does not explicitly involve the time?
3. How Equation (2) would now split up into the form: function of ($q_1$)= function of ($q_2$,$q_3$,……,$q_f$) not involving $q_1$?
4. How the '$f$' constants in the process of separation of variables replace $Q_i$ instead of $q_i$?

Can anyone explain these concepts?

Excerpt from textbook:

[image]

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I have left a link of the reference pages in my question. You can read it there. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Hamilton's principal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation)$^1$ $S\equiv F$ is the sole unknown variable in [HJ equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation). E.g. in contrast the Hamiltonian $H$ is assumed to be known.
2. That's how [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) (SOV) work. It would not work if $H$ depends explicitly on time.
3. SOV depends on a symmetry of the problem. OP's textbook does not give a reason what [Hamilton's characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) $W\equiv f$ should separate. It seems the textbook makes a very strong assumption out of the blue.
4. The integration constants $\alpha^i$ are identified with the new generalized positions $Q^i$, which are known to be constants of motion, cf. Kamilton's equations.

--

$^1$ OP's textbook chooses Hamilton's principal function to be a generating function for a [CT of type 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_1_generating_function). Another popular choice is [type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function).